# SQL Query data issues

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have the following data:

```
ID       Date                 interval  interval_date            tot_activity  non-activity
22190   2011-09-27 00:00:00     1000    2011-09-27 10:00:00.000     265           15
```

I have another table with this data:

```
Date                        ID             Start                END               sched_non_activity     non_activity
10/3/2011 12:00:00 AM   HBLV-22267  10/3/2011 2:02:00 PM    10/3/2011 2:11:00 PM    540
```

Now, in the second table's non_activity field, I would like this to be the value from the first table. However, I need to capture the tot_activity - non_activity where the intervals(in 15 min increments) from the first table, fall in the same time frame as the start and end of the second table.

I have the following so far:

```
SELECT     1.ID, 1.Date, 1.interval, 1.interval_date, 1.tot_activity, 1.non_activity,
            1.tot_activity - 1.non_activity AS non_activity
FROM         table1 AS 1 INNER JOIN
                      LIST AS L ON 1.ID = L.ID INNER JOIN
                      table2 AS 2 ON 1.Date = 2.Date AND L.ID = Right(2.ID,5) 
Where 1.interval_date >= 2.Start AND 1.interval_date < 2.End

ORDER BY 1.ID, 1.interval_date
```

With this, I can already see I will be unable to capture if a start from table 2 is at 15:50, which means that I need to capture interval 15:45.

is there any way of doing this through queries, or should I be using variables, and doing the check per interval. *Any* help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the problem with your date comaprison?

Comment: Yes, I cannot wrap my head around grabbing the data from the intervals that care in the start time. As I wrote above, my intervals are every 15 minutes. So if a start time is 15:50, I need to grab the tot_activity  and non-activity from the interval that encapsulates that time, which is 15:45.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking too much from a query here.

What i would do is treat the two tables as lists ordered by time stamps and solve the problem programatically (ie not with a single query)

For example, create a function that traverses the first table in 15min increments and find the best match in the second table (i am guessing this is what you are trying to do).  Implement your function to return the same results set as your query above or store it in a temporary table.  Select from the result set. T-SQL is your friend :)

Comment: Yeah, seems that way, but I am inexperienced in variables and loops and such. THanks for your answer.

Comment: It is very useful to know things like pl/sql, t-sql etc.  They come in very handy when you encounter problem like this, and its very probable that you will encounter problems like this again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having a tough time understanding your issue, but you might have better luck with the DATEDIFF function:

```
DATEDIFF(SECOND, 1.interval_date, 2.Start) >= 0 AND DATEDIFF(SECOND, 1.interval_date, 2.End) <= 0
```

I apologize if I'm not catching your drift. If I'm missing something, could you try to clarify a little bit?

Comment: Don't worry, I always have such a hard time explaining things it seems. As best as I can describe it, table one has login data by interval for certain statuses in seconds. Table two has scheduled data for the same statuses, but with a start and end time. Table two sometimes has incorrect data, so I go in table 1 and and verify between the datetimes of table two, to see how much activity is in table one, compared to table two. Does this make sense as an explanation?

Comment: I think I kind of get it. I think it's just a difficult problem to explain. Would doing a DATEDIFF comparison by the second help?

Comment: Not entirely. As loud wrote below, perhaps this is an issue solved using t-SQL.